# Groupby mean doesn't display all data

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want to see all the means of the numerical columns, grouped by position, using

```
dfMockPos.groupby(['Position']).mean()
```

When I do this I only get 3 of the many columns

[image]

The other columns are all integers or floats, and they have no NAs.

If I do

```
dfMockPos['Weight'].mean()
```

Then I get the correct output. How can I display weight using groupby?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What does dfMockPos.info() return?  Please update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the Aggregate function on groupby.

For example:

```
dfMockPos.groupby(['Position']).agg({"relative_age":'mean',
                                             "Height": 'mean',
                                             "Success_score": "mean",
                                             "Weight": "mean" })
```